# How to pass variable reference to Observable subscription

Tags: javascript, scope, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to get tweets from Twitter, and then get the hashtags from those tweets and get images from Flickr.

I want the tweets and images to be united together. However, see the console logs at the end. I expect the first one will output the current tweet and the second will output the images retrieved for this tweet.

However, what happens is that `console.log(tweets[i])` always prints out the last tweet in the list, while `console.log(results)` prints the current results (i.e. every flickr result is printed).

By the way, the tweets and flicks are being retrieved from a json file for now.

```
tweets$.subscribe((tweets) => {
            for (var i in tweets) {
                var hashtags = tweets[i].entities.hashtags;
                for (var j in hashtags) {
                    var flicks$ = this.flickrService.getImagesMock(hashtag[j]);
                    flicks$.subscribe((results) => {
                        console.log(tweets[i]);
                        console.log(results);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

So my question is, how do I get the `tweets[i]` in the `$flicks.subscribe` to refer to the `i` that was in use when the subscription was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's a clasical problem with scope in async js.

```
for (var i in tweets) {
    (function(index) {
        var hashtags = tweets[index].entities.hashtags;
        for (var j in hashtags) {
            var flicks$ = this.flickrService.getImagesMock(hashtag[j]);
            flicks$.subscribe((results) => {
                console.log(tweets[index]);
                console.log(results);
            });
        }        
    })(i);
}
```

Basically, in your example nested subscribe is executed after first loop is already finished.